# How can I control which keyboard is active and which is inactive (at one instant of time) in a multi-keyboard system?

Tags: c#, keyboard

I have one textbox and one label. The textbox is focused all the time (using LostFocus eventhandler). When the user presses the 'Enter' key, the textbox value is displayed in the label. [I am using C# to create a Windows 10 Universal Application.]

The problem is, this has to be implemented on a multi-keyboard system. If person P1 enters a value using keyboard K1 and person P2 types anything at the same time using K2, a "mixed" value is entered. For example, P1 wants to type 13 and P2 wants to type 24, the value might become 123 or 1324 or 1234 (depending upon the order they are typed in and the pressing of the Enter key). What I need is to make sure that only one keyboard can type at one time.

If P1 starts typing using K1, K2 should be disabled until P1 presses Enter key and vice versa. How can this be attained? [Or can it solved using some hardware device?]

Comment: Can you distinguish the keyboards for example from the speed that inputs are received?

Comment: Not really. Both the keyboards are USB keyboards and thus I can't distinguish them. Any idea how that can be done?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following approach:
[Using Raw Input from C# to handle multiple keyboards](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17123/Using-Raw-Input-from-C-to-handle-multiple-keyboard)